# Javascript returning undefined for index that is defined

Tags: javascript, debugging, memory, indexing, mapping

I created arrays of random numbers in Python and reading them in Javascript via .txt files. The final product of reading the files is a 3 dimensional array, whenever I log this array I get my expected result, but if I try to index it undefined is returned.

```
    document.getElementById('inputfile').addEventListener('change',
            function (){
                var c_file_=[]
                var fr=[];
                var blocks=[];
                for(x=0;x<this.files.length;x++){
                    fr.push(new FileReader());
                    const f=x;
                    fr[f].readAsText(this.files[f])    
                    fr[f].onloadend=function(){
                        file=(fr[f].result)
                        if(file==null){
                            console.log('read_fail')
                            c_file_.push(file_[f-1])
                        }else{
                            blocks=file.split("\n")
                            string=[]
                            for(b=0;b<blocks.length;b++){
                                string.push(blocks[b].split("], ["))
                                string[b][0]=string[b][0].replaceAll('[[',"")
          string[b][string[b].length-1]=string[b][string[b].length-1].replaceAll(']]',"")
                            }
                            values=[]
                            for(i=0;i<string.length;i++){
                                values.push([])
                                for(n=0;n<string[i].length;n++){
                                    values[i].push(parseFloat(string[i][n]))
                                }  
                            }
                            c_file_.push(values);
                        }
                    } 
                }    
                    console.log(c_file_)
            })
```

This is what gets logged if I log the whole array:

`0: (3) [Array(8), Array(4), Array(1)] 1: (3) [Array(8), Array(4), Array(1)] 2: (3) [Array(8), Array(4), Array(1)]`

But if I log `c_file_[0]` I get undefined.

I've tried using spread to map the array, mapping the array before assigning values, and various cloning methods to avoid memory leaks. Nothing has allowed me to access the value of the final array though. I'm new to javascript so I may be missing something obvious here but I can't make sense of it returning undefined for something that seems to be defined.

Comment: are you sure it exists at the time you're trying to access it?

Comment: Your JS code doesn't look valid to me.

Comment: What is `[tag:function` supposed to be?

Comment: Always declare your local variables.  Use `for(let x = ...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Console.log of an object in a browser generally shows the object's content  when it gets expanded in the developers' console, *not the properties and values it had when logged in JavaScript*. In other words `console.log(object)` does not take a cloned snapshot of `object`. However, if you don't expand console output until after all files have been read, you will see the values generated from the files.

On the other hand `console.log(undefined)` logs "undefined" on the console immediately.

In the posted code, `c_file_` has items pushed to it asynchronously in the `loadend` event handler after the file has finished being read. The `console.log` line in the post, however, is called synchronously before any file has been read. Hence, if you log the value of `c_file_[0]` in the same position, expect to see `undefined` because the `c_file_` array is still empty.

Comment: Thank you, It worked when I put the function to use the data inside the main for loop so it was asynchronous with the values being added.